# How to import class dynamic with type hint in python?

Tags: python

I'm creating websocket classes for many crypto exchange..

hear is file structure..

[image]

Each file has own websocket stream handler

```py
class binanceusdm(AbstractStream):

    async def on_open(self, ws):

    async def on_message(self, msg):

    async def on_error(self, code, reason):

    def run(self):
```

In `stream.py`, import websocket stream dynamicaly by class name

```
from feeds import streams


def create(param):
    try:
        stream = getattr(streams, param)

    except AttributeError as e:
        raise AttributeError("Unknown stream") from e

    return stream
```

But in create function, code cannot infer class type..

When I use this create function like this,

```
s = stream.create("binanceusdm")()  # -> Any
```

just returning `Any` type class

How to make type aware function `create` ?
[image]

Comment: You need some explicit mapping of class names to classes (like a `TypedDict`). You can't really type modules, and anything that would let you *statically* check `s: binanceusdm = create("binanceusdm")` would require you to know the contents of `services` ahead of time.